# Sending a group of large buffers from express to flask

Tags: javascript, express, multer

I'm trying to send a group of .mp4 files first from a web browser client, then to express, then to flask. This code might look simple, but it has taken literally days to get this far, because nobody on the internet has posted an example of how to do this with large files (.mp4 video files), and to be honest, there are a lot of inconsistencies in using these libraries.

I think it might be an encoding error from express to Flask, however. The actual data seems to be being transferred, but ffmpeg doesn't recognize the received .mp4 files as a valid video file.

From the client, I send an XHR request like this:

```
var formData = new FormData();
for(var x=0; x< datas.videoDatas.length; x++){
    // data.videoDatas[x] is a blob of a .mp4 file. it can be played 
    formData.append(x+"_video.mp4",datas.videoDatas[x]); 

}
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", 'http://localhost:3000/uploadVid', true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(this.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status == 200) {
         console.log(xhr.response);
    }
}
xhr.onload=console.log;
xhr.send(formData);
```

The express server at port 3000 receives the post request using the "multer" library. Data is stored into memory as a buffer.

```
var express = require('express');
var multer=require("multer");
var request=require("request")
var app = express();
var storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({
    storage: storage
}).any();
app.post('/uploadVid',function(req,res){
    var originalResponse=res;
    console.log("begin upload");
    upload(req, res, function(err) {
            console.log("begin upload to flask server");
            var requestStruct={
              url: 'http://localhost:3001/receiveUpload2?numFiles='+req.files.length,
              method: 'POST',
              form: {
              }
            }
            for(var x=0; x < req.files.length; x++){
                var testBuffer=req.files[x].buffer; // should be a buffer of the .mp4 file
                //testBuffer = new Buffer(10);
                //testBuffer=testBuffer.toString();
                requestStruct.form[x+'_customBufferFile']= {
                      value: testBuffer,
                      options: {
                    filename: req.files[x].fieldname
                      }
                    }
            }
            request(requestStruct, function(err,res,body){
                originalResponse.send(body)
            });
    });
});
http.createServer(app).listen(3000)
```

In the python flask server, the .mp4 files are received as a buffer and written to a .mp4 file. However, the .mp4 file is unplayable by ffmpeg "Unknown EBML doctype '(none)'0/0   0_video.mp4: End of file"

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request; 
app = Flask(__name__);
@app.route('/receiveUpload2', methods=["POST"])
def receiveUpload2():
    print("uploaded received....");
    numFiles=int(request.args.get("numFiles").encode('ascii', 'ignore'));
    print("numFiles",int(numFiles));
    for x in range(0,numFiles):
        name=request.form.getlist(str(x)+'_customBufferFile[options][filename]');
        name=name[0];
        print("writing",name);
        filebytes=request.form.getlist(str(x)+'_customBufferFile[value]');
        filebytes=filebytes[0];
        #print(filebytes);
        newFileByteArray = bytearray(filebytes,'utf8')
        with open("./uploads/"+name,"wb") as output:
            output.write(newFileByteArray);

app.run(host="localhost", port=3001);
```

Comment: Have you considered merging both servers into one? Or switching the flask server into an express server?

Comment: The express server handles client authentication very well already